# set spesific order on tabel admin area react js

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Recently i get project from other team and my client want to change some part from admin page.i want to ask how to set spesific order for data from database.for example in this case my client want to set the jabatan in spesific order
like example they want to put executive director on number one and so on
Sorry for the bad english

[image: here the table i want to set the order]

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';
import { Space, Card, Table, Button, Typography, message } from 'antd';

import { EDIT_MANAJEMEN } from '@constants/urls';

import type { ManagementProps } from '@customTypes/aboutUs';

import fetchRequest from '@utils/fetcher';
import PreviewImage from '@components/PreviewImage';

const { Title } = Typography;

const Management = () => {
  const [managementData, setManagementData] = useState<ManagementProps[]>([]);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const managementColumns = [
    {
      title: 'No',
      dataIndex: 'key',
      key: 'key'
    },
    {
      title: 'Jabatan',
      dataIndex: 'otherData',
      render: (_: string, record: any) => <>{record.otherData.position}</>,
    },
    {
      title: 'Foto',
      dataIndex: 'url',
      render: (_: string, record: any) => (
        <PreviewImage
          key="key"
          buttonName="Lihat Foto"
          mediaUrl={record.url}
        ></PreviewImage>
      ),
    },
    {
      title: 'Nama',
      dataIndex: 'title',
    },
    {
      title: 'Narasi',
      dataIndex: 'content',
      render: (_: string, record: any) => <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: record.content}}></div>,
    },
    {
      title: 'Aksi',
      key: 'action',
      render: (_: string, record: any) => (
        <Button
          type="link"
          className="button-link-grey"
          onClick={() => navigate(EDIT_MANAJEMEN + '/' + record.id)}
        >
          Ubah
        </Button>
      ),
      width: 150,
    },
  ];

  const getManagementData = async () => {
    try {
      await fetchRequest({
        method: 'GET',
        path: 'resource/about-us/management',
      }).then((response) => {
        if (!response.error) {
          setManagementData(response.management || {});
        } else {
          message.error(response.error.message);
        }
      });
    } catch (error: any) {
      message.error(error.message);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getManagementData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Space direction="vertical" size="middle" style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      <Card title={<Title level={4}>Manajemen</Title>}>
        <Table
          columns={managementColumns}
          dataSource={managementData}
          pagination={false}
        />
      </Card>
    </Space>
  );
};

export default Management;
```

[image: error]

Please tell me how to make it happend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So , here an very ugly solution, but this work for and ONLY work for the case of this ordrer "Executive Director,GA Manager , Research and Consulting Manager , Executive Learning Manager ,BOD Manager".

You have to inject this code in the condition :

```
if (!response.error) {
   //Put the code here
}
```

First create an array :

```
const order = ["Executive Director","General Affairs Manager" , "Research and Consulting Manager" , "Executive Learning Manager" ,"Businesses and Organization Development Manager"]
```

Then, create an empty array :

```
let newManagement = [] as any
```

After this, iterate on the array ordrer to fill the array  newMangement

```
for (const eltOrder of order ) {
  newManagement.push(response.management?.find((r:any) => r?.otherData?.position === eltOrder ))
}
```

Then , put this value in the state.

```
setManagementData(newMangement || {});
```

Comment: why error like this  ',' expected. after for ?

Comment: Can you send me a screenshot of your code and your error please ?

Comment: how to send the screenshot to you?

Comment: Edit your first message and use markdown to display an image

Comment: done add the screenshot @laux98

Comment: It was a missing parenthesis

Replace with this 

`
for (const eltOrder of order ) {
      newManagement.push(response.management?.find((r:any) => r?.otherData?.position === eltOrder ))
    }
`

Comment: its working thank you so muchh for your help i really appreciate it

Comment: You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two solutions for your problem.

#### First solution

You have to do a specific treatment on the managementData array before display it.

You have also to put another key in this array, for example "order" than determines the order of the array.

You can use the function sort() on a array to organise your array with a function.

For example, i find this example to sort an array by string of char :

```
var tableauObjets = [
  {nom:'Mélanie', age: 29},
  {nom:'Henrique', age: 35},
  {nom:'Stan', age: 10},
  {nom:'Mac', age: 2}
];

tableauObjets.sort(function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.nom < b.nom)
     return -1;
  if (a.nom > b.nom )
     return 1;
  return 0;
});

console.log(tableauObjets);
/* Update the array to [{
  age: 35,
  nom: "Henrique"
}, {
  age: 2,
  nom: "Mac"
}, {
  age: 29,
  nom: "Mélanie"
}, {
  age: 10,
  nom: "Stan"
}] */
```

Here some documentation and examples :

[Function sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

#### Second solution :

You can use the drag & drop on the Table Component so you can change at all moment the order of row in table.

[Drag & drop demo](https://ant.design/components/table#components-table-demo-drag-sorting)

Comment: what specific treatment i have to on the managementData and how to add order key?

Comment: For add an ordrer key, you can iterate on the array and add for exemple an integer as key.

`for (let i = 0 ; i < response.management.length ; i++) 
 response.mangement[i].key = i`

Comment: Sorry but @laux98 How to sort jabatan to this spesific order Executive Director,GA Manager
, Research and Consulting Manager
, Executive Learning Manager
,BOD Manager

Comment: Can you show me the structure the content of response.management please ?

Comment: how to get the content?

Comment: Try to display it in the console with 
console.log(respons?mangement) before the line
setManagementData(response.management || {});

Comment: all of the content?

Comment: like this or all the data?    @laux98                                                                                                              
0: 
1. content: "S1 - Sarjana Teknik, Universitas"
2. createdAt: "2022-05-26T14:09:18.887Z"
3. id: "0f6cdb7b-fd0f-4fef-b919-e79d60555573"
4. otherData: {position: 'Businesses and Organization Development Manager'}
5. subType: "Management"
6. title: " Shitta."
7. type: "AboutUs"
8. updatedAt: "2023-10-11T15:51:45.949Z"
9. url: 
10. [[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: All the data please

Comment: 1: 
1. content: S1 - Sarjana Teknik, Universitas”
2. createdAt: "2022-05-26T14:08:42.596Z"
3. id: "8b4eae98-ebf6-4dd8-ad1d-a2dd0cda2557"
4. otherData: {position: 'Executive Learning Manager'}
5. subType: "Management"
6. title: "Thirafi "
7. type: "AboutUs"
8. updatedAt: "2023-10-11T09:58:38.169Z"
9. url: 
10. [[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: 2: 
1. content: “Executive Director Astagatra Institute”
2. createdAt: "2022-05-26T14:07:53.593Z"
3. id: "90cf12f1-3fd3-41de-b56a-9d1af271d362"
4. otherData: {position: 'Executive Director'}
5. subType: "Management"
6. title: " Agus Asrama"
7. type: "AboutUs"
8. updatedAt: "2023-10-11T08:25:06.752Z"
9. url:
10. [[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: 3: 
1. content: S1 - Sarjana Ilmu Komunikasi, STIKOM InterStudi”
2. createdAt: "2022-05-26T14:08:24.910Z"
3. id: "e2263707-8d74-4dc9-afa7-641442f8fff8"
4. otherData: {position: 'General Affairs Manager'}
5. subType: "Management"
6. title: "Agustina"
7. type: "AboutUs"
8. updatedAt: "2023-08-19T03:05:16.085Z"
9. url: 
10. [[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: 4: 
1. content: “S1 - Sarjana Ekonomi, Institut Pertanian Bogor”
2. createdAt: "2022-05-26T14:09:00.027Z"
3. id: "ef7a8c60-779e-4ea6-aded-c14ac0817389"
4. otherData: {position: 'Research and Consulting Manager'}
5. subType: "Management"
6. title: "Ikhsan "
7. type: "AboutUs"
8. updatedAt: "2023-06-09T02:05:11.855Z"
9. url: 
10. [[Prototype]]: Object
6. length: 5
7. [[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Comment: thats all the data

Comment: Is the result when you console.log the repons.mangement ?

Comment: Yess it is the result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255611/discussion-between-laux98-and-esther).